# Semantic-UI dropdowns inside a horizontal-scroll DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overflow, semantic-ui

I am trying to include Semantic-UI dropdowns inside a table with many columns, which has a horizontal scroll bar.

When clicking a dropdown, the options are hidden inside the div.

**fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/rotemx/n0azk0jc/

**code:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <div style="width: 500px">
      <div class="inline-block">
        <div class="ui selection dropdown">
          <input type="hidden" name="gender">
          <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          <div class="default text">Gender</div>
          <div class="menu">
            <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
            <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="inline-block">
        <div class="ui selection dropdown">
          <input type="hidden" name="gender">
          <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          <div class="default text">Gender</div>
          <div class="menu">
            <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
            <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="inline-block">
        <div class="ui selection dropdown">
          <input type="hidden" name="gender">
          <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          <div class="default text">Gender</div>
          <div class="menu">
            <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
            <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**screenshot:** 
[image]

**quesiton:**
How can I make the dropdowns visible ?

Comment: fiddle link dead?

Comment: sorry, wrong url - fixed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current setup, you can't. Anything inside the element with *overflow: none* cannot be shown outside the element boundaries.